# JDBC persistence layer?

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, jdbc

I'm looking around and I can't find any good examples or methods to make a JDBC persistence layer. I'd use a framework but I don't have the time to fix errors and such.

So, how am I supposed to make a persistence layer in a JSP/JSF system using exclusively JDBC?

Comment: Why do you want to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: "how am I supposed to make a persistence layer in a JSP/JSF system using exclusively JDBC?" that's going to be way, way more time consuming than using an existing framework.

Comment: Wait, I seriously don't have choice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What makes you think that you will have to fix errors in a framework? Have a look at Spring and especially its [JDBCTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/jdbc.html). It will ease jdbc-pain a lot and I wouldn't expect you to find (m)any errors there.

Comment: Spring looks beautiful. I think I'll give it a go, thank you.

Comment: Haha, yep, I was just waiting to be allowed to accept the question :)!